# Solr query boosting syntax errors

Tags: solr

I'm reading Solr 1.4: Enterprise Search Server and there's a section on enhanced searching that I am a bit stuck on how to get the query to behave in the way described by the book.

In the book, it has what I assume a query,

```
t_name:Daydreaming && _val_:"t_trm_lookups"^0.01
```

I'm trying to emulate this query in my own Solr but I get an error when I try.

```
HTTP ERROR: 400

undefined field symbol

RequestURI=/solr/select

Powered by Jetty://
```

Comment: I guess you are trying to assign weights to fields  http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ . And that syntax seems like Lucene (instead of Solr). But I could be totally wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a field name t_trm_lookups (type int or sint) in the schema.xml that you are using to get the boost on ?